# how to remove vista service pack 1 information

Tags: windows-vista

i had a failed SP1 install...

now im stuck with the system trying (and failing) to finilize instalation @boot,

the system after log-in thinks its SP1

SP1 uninstaller says it cant uninstall

SP1 installer says allready installed

SP2 installer says install SP1

---

is there a way to remove SP1 information, fool the system to think it doesnt have service pack and install it again ?

i REALLY dont want to reinstall windows. that would suck so badly that id rather stick with this pre-SP1 relic...

Comment: people i know how to use google, if it was as simple as reading an article on ms support i wouldnt waste ~20hours allready on it... if after 2 days no one comes up with an idea to fool the system to reinstall SP1 ill just get over it and reinstall windows....

Comment: Next time, think of a backup before an operation like that.

Comment: The installer should not have a check if installed then tell user to go to hell... it should be able to install new files regardless of system state.. in my opinion... but ah well

Answer (score 0):

See here for more information:[How to uninstall Windows Vista service packs as a troubleshooting step](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948537)

Comment: been there done that...

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [How to remove Vista Service Packs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948537)

Comment: been there done that...